# Why can't the Turtle screen open after running "from turtle import*"?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am running Windows 10 and unable to open the Turtle screen with the command

```
from turtle import*
```

I get the following message:

> RESTART: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/new.py

I have tried reinstalling but not luck..can you help?

Comment: Are you running your program under IDLE? Also, provide your source code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes, I am running IDLE. I am using a teacher resource book and it simply said to use the command: From turtle import* to load the program and the screen should open.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Thing 1: this answer to a reddit question on [getting RESTART: message](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3wi66q/total_beginner_getting_restart_message/) states that *it's not* an error but just part of how IDLE restarts itself.

Thing 2: on my system, not using IDLE, the command `from turtle import *` *is not* sufficient to open the turtle window.  Follow it with a `Screen()` command, for example, to open the window.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks but I have also tried that, based on some other research and I get the following:RESTART: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/new.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/new.py", line 2, in <module>
    screen()
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Oh Thanks...it worked but no turtle appeared on the screen:-(

Comment: Issue a turtle command, or create a new turtle, and the turtle will appear. E.g. type `dot()`.